# Blur the background without filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a website and I have this code that blur out the background:

**CSS**

```
#background{ 
    background: url(img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: calc(100% - 96px);
    -o-transition: all 750ms;
    -moz-transition: all 750ms;
    -webkit-transition: all 750ms;
    transition: all 750ms
}

.covered{
    background: url(img/bgb.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed!important;
    -webkit-background-size: cover!important;
    -moz-background-size: cover!important;
    -o-background-size: cover!important;
    background-size: cover!important;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.overlay,.ov').click(function(){
    $('#background').addClass('covered');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="background">
    //content of my page
</div>
```

I tried:

-Using `blur filter` but the content blurs out too.

-Using a sprite but since my backgrounds needs to be centered it appears the top part normal, and the bottom part blurred.

My current code works great but the image has to load and when you click overlay/ov the background turns white until the new blurry background fully loaded. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try forcing browser to download image by creating `Image` element, either in html or in javascript. Try adding

```
<img src="img/bgb.jpg" style="display:none">`
```

to html or

```
var bbg = new Image();
bbg.src = "img/bgb.jpg";
```

to javascript. It doesn't have to be shown anywhere to force resource download. In facts, even bare `new Image().src = "img/bgb.jpg";`, without any var, should be enough.

When you switch the background with css, blurred image will be already loaded into browser's cache and should show immediately.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to hack together something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Then adjust the positioning of the background:

```
.background {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that mess up the bg? Gonna try it anyway