# Javascript: How to change the images inside of a div on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I am trying to create the effect seen on this website (for the photos on the left side of the column):
https://www.franshalsmuseum.nl/en/

I want to be able to change the image on scroll inside of a div.
And preferably, it won't scroll down past the page until all of the images have been scrolled through!

I'm trying to get the hang of javascript before adding things like jQuery, so can someone help with this using pureJS?`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    console.log(window.pageYOffset);
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    var img2 = document.getElemebtById('img2')
    if ( window.pageYOffset > 1000 ) {
        img1.classList.add("hidden");
        img2.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
        img2.classList.add("hidden");
        img1.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
}
```

```css
.rightPhotos {
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.aPhoto {
    max-height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.images {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
      <div class="other">
          <div class="rightPhotos" onscroll="myFunction()">
              <div class="aPhoto">
                  <img class ="images" id="img1" src="IMAGES/sunglasses.jpeg"  alt="Woman with Sunglasses">
              </div>
              <div class="aPhoto hidden">
                  <img class="images" src="IMAGES/dancer1.jpg" alt="A Dancer">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

`

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2):

The page you linked actually looks very nice, so I took a while to make something looking a bit closer to it than what other answers do.

- I added a properly working transition, similar to one on franshalsmuseum.nl.
- I styled the page to deal relatively well with being resized:

  - The sizing of panes and images is all ralative,
  - Scroll steps are relative to page height,
  - Images are shown using `<div>` with `background-image` instead of `<img>` tag. Depending on the size of the window, they are slightly cropped to adjust to changing aspect ratio of viewport.
- I made the number of image sets very simple to change. It could be improved by creating the html elements in Javascript, but that doesn't look necessary. At least, it wouldn't be for the original page.

#### How it works

**HTML**

Images are put into special envelop elements (`.img-wrapper`), that provide proper sizing and positioning `position: relative` is important there). Each image element gets url (as background image url) and image set number to be used by javascript:

```
<div class="img visible" data-imageset="1"
    style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/people');">
</div>
```

Class visible is set to show imageset 1 at the beginning.

**CSS**

The key points are these definitions (and similar for `#bottom-image`). As the element enveloping the image has `overflow: hidden`, we can hide the image by moving it outside of visible area. When we set coordinates back to normal, the image will slide back, using the smooth transition.

```
/* hiding images in #top-image */
#left-pane #top-image .img {
  top: 100%;
}
#left-pane #top-image .img.visible {
  top: 0;
}
```

**JS**

The Javascript code is very minimal, the interaction with DOM is really one line. However, it uses some tricks that may not be obvious, so there is this line with some links to documentation:

`document`.[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)`('#left-pane .img')`.[`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)(`(img)` [`=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) { 
    `img`.[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).[`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)(`'visible'`, `img`.[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).`imageset` `<=` `currentSet`); 
}

It just finds all images and adds or removes class `visible` depending on the `data-imageset` attribute of the image.

**Full snippet with demo**

See snippet below. Demo looks much better if you use "Full page" link after running the snippet.

```js
let currentSet = 1;

function updateSelectedImgSet() {
  const currentScroll = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  const scrollMax = document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight - document.scrollingElement.clientHeight;
  const setsCount = 3;
  const scrollPerSet = scrollMax / setsCount;
  const scrolledSet = Math.floor(currentScroll / scrollPerSet) + 1;
  if (scrolledSet == currentSet) {
    return;
  }
  currentSet = scrolledSet;
  document.querySelectorAll('#left-pane .img').forEach((img) => {
    img.classList.toggle('visible', img.dataset.imageset <= currentSet);
  });
}

window.onscroll = updateSelectedImgSet;
window.onresize = updateSelectedImgSet;
```

```css
/* Left pane, fixed */
#left-pane {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40vw;
}

#left-pane .img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#left-pane .img-wrapper .img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* Sizing and cropping of image */
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  /* Transition - the slow sliding of images */
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
}

/* hiding images in #top-image */
#left-pane #top-image .img {
  top: 100%;
}
#left-pane #top-image .img.visible {
  top: 0;
}

/* hiding images in #bottom-image */
#left-pane #bottom-image .img {
  bottom: 100%;
}
#left-pane #bottom-image .img.visible {
  bottom: 0;
}

/* Right pane, scrolling with the page */

#right-pane {
  margin-left: 40vw;
}

.scrollable-content {
  font-size: 40vw;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="left-pane">
  <div id="top-image" class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img visible" data-imageset="1"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/people');">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-imageset="2"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/animals');">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-imageset="3"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/any');">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom-image" class="img-wrapper">
    <div class="img visible" data-imageset="1"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/nature');">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-imageset="2"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/tech');">
    </div>
    <div class="img" data-imageset="3"
        style="background-image: url('http://placeimg.com/640/480/arch');">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="right-pane">
  <div class="scrollable-content">Scrollable content!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**see code bellow:**`(I set 60 insteed 1000 (in function)for see changes)`
I use **one** `image` and `onscroll` change the `src` of image

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
    var img2 = document.getElementById('img2')
    if ( window.pageYOffset > 60 ) {
 document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg";
    } else {
 document.getElementById("img1").src = "https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg";
    }
}
```

```css
.rightPhotos
{
    max-width: 50%;
    height:50%;

    overflow: auto;
}
.aPhoto
{

    max-height: 100%;


}



.images
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
      <div class="other">
         <div class="rightPhotos" onscroll="myFunction()">
           <div class="aPhoto">
               <img class ="images" id="img1" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"  alt="Woman with Sunglasses"/>
   </div>

  </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Hi! I'm wondering if it's possible to hang it so that the images change as the user scrolls, however the page doesn't actually move past that div until all of the pictures have been rotated/shown?

Comment: @sGlow if the issue is about images loading slowly, you need to preload them. Either have them loaded all the time (like in my answer), or use some additional elements/JS [to force preloading them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042886/blur-the-background-without-filter/29043406#29043406).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS properties to show/ hide the elements; instead of having custom CSS with hidden class.

```
if ( window.pageYOffset > 1000 ) {
        img1.style.visibility = 'hidden';  
        img2.style.visibility = 'visible';  
    } else {
        img2.style.visibility = 'hidden';  
        img1.style.visibility = 'visible';  
}
```

The above would hide the element, but the DOM element would still occupy space.

For it now to have space occupied (like to remove it)

```
if ( window.pageYOffset > 1000 ) {
        img1.style.display = 'none';
        img2.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        img1.style.display = 'block';
        img2.style.display = 'none'; 
}
```

Comment: How is it better than having a `.hidden` class in CSS, that would do just the same but in a cleaner way?

Comment: It would be the same, just that we don't need to have custom CSS and avoid adding/ removing class. The 2nd CSS removes the element from the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```js
//window.pageYOffset

var scrollingDiv = document.getElementById('scrollContainer');
var img1 = document.getElementById('img1');
var img2 = document.getElementById('img2');

  scrollingDiv.onscroll = function(event) {

  if (scrollingDiv.scrollTop < 500) {
    img1.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/arch";
    img2.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/animals";
  }
  
  if (scrollingDiv.scrollTop > 500) {
    img1.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/nature";
    img2.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/people";
  }
  if (scrollingDiv.scrollTop > 1000) {
    img1.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/tech";
    img2.src = "https://placeimg.com/250/100/any";
  }
 
  
}
```

```css
.container{
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 body{
 margin: 0;
 }
.container > div {
  vertical-align:top;
 }
 .left, .middle, .right {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100vh;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   
 }
 .left, .right{
   width:40%;
   background: gray;
 }
 
 .middle{
   overflow: auto;
   position: relative;
 }
 
 .in-middle{
   background: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
 }
 .in-in-middle{
   height: 500px;
   background: tomato;
 }
 
 .in-in-middle:nth-child(2){
  background: pink;
 }
 
 .in-in-middle:nth-child(3){
  background: skyblue;
 }
 
 .left img{
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <img id="img1" src="https://placeimg.com/250/100/arch">
    <img id="img2" src="https://placeimg.com/250/100/animals">
  </div>
  <div class="middle" id="scrollContainer">
    <div class="in-middle">
      <div class="in-in-middle" id="1"></div>
      <div class="in-in-middle" id="2"></div>
      <div class="in-in-middle" id="3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work. Seems like you messed up conditions, you have `> 500` twice. Which is why you should use `else`, btw.

Comment: @Frax I meant to use less than operator on first. I know I can use else. Even switch for that matter, but I wanted to keep it simple for op. Btw snippet does work just wait for the img to load.

Comment: @Frax Just let the pink section hit the top after that images will change if you wait a little and scroll further